# Não consigo logar no phpmyadmin no projeto usando Laradock (Laravel e Docker)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Eu sou iniciante e comecei um projeto PHP usando o ambiente Laradock. Pois bem, eu tenho tudo instalado e configurado, os conteiners todos rodando e consigo acessar o projeto em desenvolvimento e tudo. Porém, eu não estou conseguindo logar no phpmyadmin para trabalhar com as tabelas do banco! Todas as vezes que eu tento, o sistema me retorna as mesmas mensagens:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Meu arquivo env está assim:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cursolaravel55-saldo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Meu arquivo database.php está assim:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Quando eu vou no phpmyadmin e insiro localhost como servidor, ele já exibe a mensagem:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Eu já mudei o host para 127.0.0.1, para localhost, para laradock_mysql_1, não deu certo. Também fiz downgrade para a versão 5.7 do mysql, mas acho que não deu certo, pois na instalação ele dá a entender que está baixando a versão mais recente. Enfim, se alguém puder me ajudar com essa.

---

Quando eu dou o comando docker-compose build mysql, ele só baixa a versão mais recente do mysql:

```
docker-compose build mysql
Building mysql
Step 1/9 : ARG MYSQL_VERSION=latest
Step 2/9 : FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
 ---> c7109f74d339
Step 3/9 : LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c0b9c7a2ddbc
Step 4/9 : ARG TZ=UTC
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29cc3fbb98b5
Step 5/9 : ENV TZ ${TZ}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ba4922aa424
Step 6/9 : RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9dcfcf5a481
Step 7/9 : COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3844813c2d51
Step 8/9 : CMD ["mysqld"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e8d89e0eb210
Step 9/9 : EXPOSE 3306
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0518339c2556
Successfully built 0518339c2556
Successfully tagged laradock_mysql:latest
```

mesmo eu editando o arquivo .env e colocando que quero a versão 5.7.

Comment: Tem alguma dessas coisas que vc está rodando em docker  ?

Comment: Sim. Eu inicio os containers e através do comando docker ps eu consigo ver que todos estão rodando, incluindo mysql e phpmyadmin

Comment: Já tentou localhost:porta, localhost/phpmyadmin, localhost:porta/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Não dá certo. Só consigo acessar atráves de localhost:8080

Comment: Tem como vc postar o comando que usa pra subir esses containers ? Pq ta me parecendo que a porta do phpmyadmin nao foi mapeada, por isso vc nao consegue acessar, mas nao tenho certeza pq nao sei como vc ta instanciando esses containers =)

Answer (score 1):

Pare Todos os serviços `docker-compose down`
Edite o arquivo `.env` e defina `MYSQL_VERSION=5.7` ou `MYSQL_VERSION=latest`

```
### Deleta a base mysql
$ rm -rf ~/.laradock/data/mysql

### remonta a imagem mysql 
$ docker-compose build mysql

### recriar
$ docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Mais detalhes nesse [link](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1407) ou no [Guia](https://laradock.io/guides/) laradock.

Comment: é para eu deletar toda a pasta mysql de laradock? pq a minha variável do arquivo env está assim: DATA_PATH_HOST=~/.laradock/data

Comment: Eu tentei fazer do jeito acima e não deu certo. Daí eu fui no arquivo Dockerfile da pasta mysql e coloquei essas instruções: ARG MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
FROM mysql:5.7. Porém no final ele baixou a versão 8 do mysql.

Comment: Cássia, segue esse link https://medium.com/@thicolares/como-configurar-um-ambiente-completo-php-nginx-mysql-e-phpmyadmin-para-projetos-laravel-usando-99954285351e

Comment: Nesse link ele explica exatamente o mesmo erro que voce está enfrentando